"Fill", "fit" and "cover" with an image in splash screen of Flutter application
I am developing a flutter app, for android. My goal is to implement a splash screen with an image, fitting horizontally and keeping aspect ratio (vertically won't cover but I will use a color in the layer-list). But in general I want to be able to implement the three "classic" ways to scale it (besides tiling) which is (in plain words):

fill: that's clear, scale independently horizontally and vertically to match the screen, not respecting aspect ratio.
fit: scale respecting aspect ratio until one dimension matches the screen, and the other is shorter, not covering the whole screen.
cover: scale respecting aspect ratio until one dimension matches the screen and the other exceeds it, effectively covering the whole screen.

With the added complexity that the image size is smaller than the screen of the device. In other words, the image will need to be upscaled in the splash screen.
I have a launch theme that precedes a normal theme when running my app, defined in the styles.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Then, the launch_background.xml present in two folders (drawable and drawable-v21):

The one that is being used by my phone when debugging:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" /> -->
    <item>
        <color android:color="#ffffff"/> <!-- Replace #FFFFFF with your desired hex color -->
        <!-- <color android:color="#1D1D1D"/> Replace #FFFFFF with your desired hex color -->
    </item>

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            ...
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

The three dots should be substituted by options for bitmap. I have tried every value alone and together of android:gravity and android:scaleType (single values for each, not combined values with the | operator), and I only get two outcomes.
If the image is larger than the screen, I get either:

Fill
Fit (horizontal since the image is almost square and the screen height is greater than its width)

But if the image is smaller than the screen, I get either:

Fill
Center (not fitted neither horizontally or vertically)

Is there a solution for this other than obtaining a high resolution image that can cover the whole screen? Some devices have a huge screen size and resolution, and I doubt that my expectation to be able to upscale an image in the splash screen while keeping aspect ratio is unreasonable.

Somebody added a comment that was either deleted by the user itself, or by a moderator. It suggested "There is a layout XML that is displayed for splash screen, there you have to tweak the root element to resize the child". I wonder if it was related with the option android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" found in the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?
